# TableView Cell image persistence using Core Data

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, core-data, uiimage

I am trying an app with a tableview which has profile name and images of people..the tableview is editable and adding new name and picture, deleting an existing one and rearranging the table are possible..the tableview and changes to it should be saved using core data..I have almost completed it but core data part is having some problems..

I have implemented core data to provide data persistence for the tablecells..everytime i restart the app, the table cell keeps the changes that were last made..but the cell image doesn't load..how to make that image persist?

```
NSManagedObject *person1 = [NSEntityDescription
                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                            inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *person2 = [NSEntityDescription
                            insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Person"
                            inManagedObjectContext:context];

[person1 setValue:@"Bruce" forKey:@"personName"];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.jpg"]; 
NSData *imageData1 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.9);
[person1 setValue:imageData1 forKey:@"personPicture"];
NSLog(@"Image1 data %@",imageData1);

[person2 setValue:@"Alfred" forKey:@"personName"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.jpg"]; 
NSData *imageData2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.9);
[person2 setValue:imageData2 forKey:@"personPicture"];

NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

then fetch was done as

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"Person" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error1 = nil;
self.persons = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error1] mutableCopy];
```

this much was done in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in appDelegate. The data was then used in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the tableview class implementation file as

```
Person *thisPerson = [persons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = thisPerson.personName;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[thisPerson valueForKey:@"personPicture"]];
if ( image == nil ) {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"QuestionMark.jpg"]; 
}
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

The cell is loading properly..and all the editing part I did is also being saved and reloaded..the images load properly when loading the app for the 1st time..when it is restarted the QuestionMark.jpg image appears..which is because the image is nil..I tried NSLog to display the 1st image data and got this:

```
2012-09-07 17:05:59.395 Sample Project[1688:fb03] Image1 data <ffd8ffe0 00104a46     
49460001 01000001 00010000 ffe10058 45786966 00004d4d 002a0000 00080002 01120003 
00000001 00010000 87690004 00000001 00000026 00000000 0003a001 00030000 00010001 
0000a002 00040000 00010000 00bea003 00040000 00010000 01090000 .........
......               .............. 7ff4d668 0356803f 357e307f c94ff14f fd858ffe 
9af4ba00 f39a00cf a00d0a00 cfa00280 0a002803 ffd9>
```

a lot more was there where i added the dots..anyway..this seems to show that its saving the data..

Comment: Please update the code to show EXACTLY what you are using now (as you said that you are not using 'UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.0);' anymore but 'UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image2, 0.9);' Also please change 'only images in having a problem' to tell us WHAT problem you are experiencing. Also after creating imageData1/imageData2 add a NSLog to verify you got a data object.

Comment: So when you set 'thisPerson.personName', that's working. Just curious - why don't you use the same syntax for the image - thisPerson.personPicture? Anyway, break out this line '[thisPerson valueForKey:@"personPicture"]', set it to a variable, then log its class and its size if it 'isKindOf:[NSData class]'. I just checked my MOM - I have 'Binary Data' as the type of this attribute.

Comment: Sorry..but I didnt get this part.."then log its class and its size if it 'isKindOf:[NSData class]'"..and I had tried with the thisPerson.personPicture format..had the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is relatively small, then save it as a NSData object in the core data repository. I do this for thumbnails etc. For huge images, you can save a URL and put the image in your Documents folder, and save a URL to the file (NSURL) as an object in Core Data too. If you delete that core data entity, it has to then delete the file.

EDIT: Regarding the "Sorry..." comment in your Question, change this line:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[thisPerson valueForKey:@"personPicture"]];
```

to

```
NSData *data = thisPerson.personPicture;
if(data) {
  NSLog(@"Image class: %@", NSStringFromClass[data class]);
  if([data isKindOfClass:[NSData data]]) {
    NSLog(@"Data was of size %u", [data length]);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    if(image) NSLOg(@"SUCCESS!");
    else NSLog(@"PROBLEM: cannot create image from data");
  }
} else {
  NSLog(@"BIG PROBEM - personPicture is nil");
}
```

You will learn much from the output here.

Comment: how small do the images have to be so as to save as NSData object?

Comment: There is no hard limit - its just that the core data repository will get really big fast if you add images that are 100Meg in size. I tend to save around 100 images which are all 50K or so in size. Convert the CGImageRef to a JPEG image to get the best compression.

Comment: Oh ok..This is a trial application that i am trying to get a hang of things..so table is quite small..and also the images are small jpeg images..so it shud work fine right?

Comment: Yes, you should be just fine.

Comment: I tried doing this..by saving it as NSData object in the core data entity..Still I am having the same trouble when i restart my application..

Comment: So when you restart it, write some test code, dump the objects in your repository, ask each object that owns the image data for that data, try to create an image from the data, see if it works or not. That will tell you if you saved it properly. If so, then you obviously have some logic problem between where you layout cells and  Core Data.

Comment: I have added the code that I used..can you please take a look?

Comment: In this call, UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1, 0.0);, you are telling the system to make the lowest possible quality image. You want 0.9 or something instead. That is most likely the problem.

Comment: Should I do something to write the data to a file and then reload it from the file?

Comment: You have a fundimental flaw in your program. You should strive to fix the problem, not cycle through different options in hope that one works. If you create a small demo project, where you put one image in the bundle, re-use your code an MOC, and when the app starts create the MOC, add the image, close the MOC, reopen it, look for the image, and its not there - then take that project and post it to DropBox, I can look at it and in 2 min tell you what is wrong. I am using Core Data to do this exact same thing, as are thousands of other people - the technology works well.

Comment: it worked out..I recreated the whole core data part from scratch and now its working fine..must have been some error in creating the managed object class..I had originally created the image attribute as tranformable type and then changed to binary data..I deleted that whole thing and did again(this time defined it as binary data) and it worked..thanks for the help..